# Shared calendars on Thunderbird lightning

Tags: outlook, scheduling, thunderbird, thunderbird-lightning

I would like to setup an open source solution for calendaring in a medium sized enterprise. We would be using this from Thunderbird (lightning add-on), Microsoft Outlook. I want to see others' free/busy schedule, invite them to meetings etc.

It would be really nice if I could have a calendar for resources like conference room, projector etc.

I have searched quite a lot on the net, but have not found a suitable solution nor any detailed instructions on how to set this up. Since this is very much needed in organizations, I am sure you might have set this up. I would be really grateful if you could provide me pointers to any detailed (step-by-step) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you need, but I like Google Calendar.

The best thing is that you need no setup.

Comment: I totally agree, I have several and share them with others.

Answer (score 2):

[Open Exchange](http://www.open-xchange.com/) does this.  Look for the community edition, and check out the community edition FAQ for how to connect thunderbird and other calenders with the WebDav publisher.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I'd second [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar/) - it's free, easy to set up and allows free SMS notifications of meetings in a number of countries, although in some countries [network operator charges may apply](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37173) for receipt of messages.

> Google Calendar is a free product and Google doesn't charge you to receive notifications. Please keep in mind that if you're in the US or Canada, your mobile service provider's standard rate for receiving text messages may apply.

There are also a number of free tools available for integrating it with your existing mail clients:

- [Thunderbird add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4631)
- Instructions for [MS Outlook integration](http://my.opera.com/sean.orear/blog/show.dml/274414)

Answer (score 0):

I created outlook categories called things like 'Meeting Room', 'Projector' and 'Vacation' and wrote a quick and dirty client/server program to sync these shared categories to each client... this was many years ago, but I suspect outlook still won't show you everyones custom categories otherwise.